# Devise - current_user nil on post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I know i had this working before, but for some reason the current_user method call in one of my create actions keeps returning nil. It works fine when used in other controller and so forth, such as a side panel to show my username.

```
class CombatInstancesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # when creating a new instance, check if the current user has one and destroy it
    CombatInstance.find(current_user.combat_instance.id).destroy if current_user.combat_instance
    # Now create the new one
    render :json => current_user.create_combat_instance
  end

  def update
    @combat_instance = current_user.combat_instance
    @combat_instance.trigger_actions(params[:actions])
    @combat_instance.perform_ai_actions
    @combat_instance.save # should we instead call this in an after hook?
    render :json => @combat_instance
  end
end
```

The line `CombatInstance.find(current_user.combat_instance.id).destroy if current_user.combat_instance` is where current_user returns nil. The workflow is: I go to the home page, i login just fine. I can see my username at the top, which is generated using the current_user helper in the view. However, when i submit a form that hits the create action here, it returns nil.

Comment: I'm not sure this is enough to go on. Can you provide more details? In what line are you getting the nil? What is the exact error/behavior you are experiencing?

Comment: If you refresh the home page after logging in, are you still logged in? What do you get on the log if you do a `RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info current_user` (Rails 2) or `Rails.logger.info current_user` (Rails 3) from within the very top of the `create` action? Do you have any `before_filters` in the `CombatInstancesController` or the `ApplicationController` that may be causing oddness?

Comment: Yes I am still logged in. When i output current_user at the top of the create action to the log file, it just outputs an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Rails 3 w/ Ajax calls?

Make sure you have

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

in your header.

Comment: Yes to both of those things. The post is made with an ajax call, and I do have the csrf_meta_tag in the head section.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The helper is built-in to devise itself, so it's not my own defined method. As I stated in my question, the helper works fine in the views and so forth. It also seems to when I put it in another controller action.

Comment: So it looks like the token was not being passed in the ajax call. I simply added it manually to the headers, and it works: https://gist.github.com/1149539. Can see the before and after files there.