# Rails Valums Ajax Upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, upload, fine-uploader

I'm trying to get Valums uploader to work with my rails project and having a lot of difficulty.

I currently have a really simple upload process with Paperclip using the standard model and view...
**Model**

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip

  has_mongoid_attached_file :image
```

**Controller**

```
  def avatar
    @user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
  #working on the updateimage method
    def update
      file = params[:qqfile].is_a?(ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile) ? params[:qqfile] : params[:file]
        @user = current_user
        if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
            render :text => '{"success": true}', :content_type => "application/json"
       else
            render :text => @user.errors.to_json, :content_type => "application/json"
       end
     end
```

**View**

```
= form_for(@user, :as => @user, :url => '/updateimage', :html => { :method => :post, :multipart => true }) do |f|
    #file-uploader
    =@user.firstname
    %img{:src => current_user.image}
    = f.file_field :image
    = f.submit
```

*Soooooo...* this all works, but when I try to use Valums jQuery:

```
  $('#file-uploader').fineUploader({
    debug: true,
    autoSubmit: true,
    allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'],
    sizeLimit: 1048576, // max size: 1MB
    minSizeLimit: 0, // min size
    multiple: false,
    request: {
        endpoint: '/updateimage',
        paramsInBody: true
        }
    });
```

I get this:

```
undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass
```

I'd love to get this working, but I'm a little new to programming in general, so it's still quite an abstract thing for me. I'm happy to provide additional log info, just tell me where to find it.

**Routes**

```
             admin_index GET    /admin(.:format)                       admin#index
                         POST   /admin(.:format)                       admin#create
               new_admin GET    /admin/new(.:format)                   admin#new
              edit_admin GET    /admin/:id/edit(.:format)              admin#edit
                   admin GET    /admin/:id(.:format)                   admin#show
                         PUT    /admin/:id(.:format)                   admin#update
                         DELETE /admin/:id(.:format)                   admin#destroy
                  orders GET    /orders(.:format)                      orders#index
                         POST   /orders(.:format)                      orders#create
               new_order GET    /orders/new(.:format)                  orders#new
              edit_order GET    /orders/:id/edit(.:format)             orders#edit
                   order GET    /orders/:id(.:format)                  orders#show
                         PUT    /orders/:id(.:format)                  orders#update
                         DELETE /orders/:id(.:format)                  orders#destroy
                 entries GET    /entries(.:format)                     entries#index
                         POST   /entries(.:format)                     entries#create
               new_entry GET    /entries/new(.:format)                 entries#new
              edit_entry GET    /entries/:id/edit(.:format)            entries#edit
                   entry GET    /entries/:id(.:format)                 entries#show
                         PUT    /entries/:id(.:format)                 entries#update
                         DELETE /entries/:id(.:format)                 entries#destroy
              home_index GET    /home(.:format)                        home#index
                         POST   /home(.:format)                        home#create
                new_home GET    /home/new(.:format)                    home#new
               edit_home GET    /home/:id/edit(.:format)               home#edit
                    home GET    /home/:id(.:format)                    home#show
                         PUT    /home/:id(.:format)                    home#update
                         DELETE /home/:id(.:format)                    home#destroy
                  avatar        /avatar(.:format)                      home#avatar
             updateimage POST   /updateimage(.:format)                 home#update
                    root        /                                      home#home
                    root        /                                      home#index
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)              devise/sessions#destroy
 user_omniauth_authorize        /users/auth/:provider(.:format)        users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/facebook/}
  user_omniauth_callback        /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format) users/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:facebook)
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)          devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)         devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                users/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                       users/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)               users/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                  users/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                       users/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                       users/registrations#destroy
       user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)          devise/confirmations#create
   new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format)      devise/confirmations#new
                         GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)          devise/confirmations#show
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                   users#show
```

Comment: Show the output of `rake routes` command.

Comment: Posted routes.  *Note*: When my endpoint is 'users', it's almost right. Meaning, I get a return in the console, but I don't actually update any info...not sure why. Currently 'users' is used to update all fields in the user profile, not just the user avatar...

Comment: *Note*: Usine Rack::RawUpload gem as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** I think it's worth trying to leave `users#update` alone and create a separate action for file uploading.

As for the routes, FineUploader performs only `POST` requests so you have to add a new route because `POST` request to `/users` endpoint would trigger `users#create` action which is not what you want.

```
match '/avatar', :to => 'users#avatar', :via => :post
```

Furthermore, you have to handle file uploading on server side. [This wiki page](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/wiki/Rails---CarrierWave) describes two methods. For instance, you can use `rack-raw-upload` gem and change controller code to the following:

```
def update
  # this action does not handle AJAX file upload
  # ...
end

def avatar
  file = params[:qqfile].is_a?(ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile) ? params[:qqfile] : params[:file]
  @user = current_user
  if @user.update_attributes({ :image => file })
    render :json => { :success => true }
  else
    render :json => { :success => false }
  end
end
```

Note that there has to be a line in `config/application.rb` (if you use `rack-raw-upload` gem):

```
config.middleware.use 'Rack::RawUpload'
```

Moreover, it seems that `paramsInBody` should belong to `request` parameter:

```
$('#file-uploader').fineUploader({
    request: {
        endpoint: "/avatar",
        paramsInBody: true
    },
    debug: true
})
```

**The final note:** CSRF token must be included in headers when making AJAX request in order to enable user authentication. It can be done by editing `setHeaders` function in `fineuploader.js` — add the following line to this function:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content"));
```

Comment: I feel like this is closer...but I'm getting an error still--at submit the user is logged out...

Comment: I'm trying a few different things, but I'm getting things like "undefined method 'update_attributes'"...I'm not sure where to go. If you can walk me through, I'll give you what I can.

Comment: @KevinBrown what happens to the model fields when the user is logged out? Are their values updated properly?

Comment: Don't think so. I did some more fooling, now I'm getting `Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id`

Comment: I've had a chance to check a little further. Can you help? Your code works (WITHOUT AJAX/VALUMS) and without .merge. I'm using mongo--does that change things? Why does this function work with regular form submission but not valums?! Do I not have rawupload configured correctly?

Comment: May it also be worth noting that I'm not using the qqUploader script but the .fineUploader jquery version?

Comment: @KevinBrown I don't think that mongo or jquery breaks it. I've updated the answer, hope it finally works.

Comment: Again, this works fine with the form submit, but not with valums...I have a separate action that does the upload, but the return of valums is 'undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass'...what the heck?

Comment: I've got exactly what you're recommending. Would it help me to update my original question for you, or can we work through this? Why won't rails/jquery/something recognize `update_attributes`?

Comment: @KevinBrown I think it would be easier to solve the problem if you update the question. As for the 'undefined method `update_attributes` for nil:NilClass' error, it means that `current_user` returns `nil` for some reason.

Comment: Alright...take a look at my update. Again, no idea why this isn't working! The errors are all in the console...if you have recommendations about how to go about debugging this, I'm all ears.

Comment: @KevinBrown the issue seems to be related to Devise since `current_user` is nil. Do you have `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in `home` controller? Also, the problem may be that CSRF token required to authenticate user is not passed in the AJAX call. (There is related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060854/devise-current-user-nil-on-post-request) on SO).

Comment: Geez...There's no `before_filter` in the home controller...but there is in the devise/user auth controller...also, my csrf is already included in the head.

Comment: @KevinBrown the question I mentioned was [solved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060854/devise-current-user-nil-on-post-request#comment8476154_7061805) by manually including token in request headers. Maybe you can do so too. For instance, you can adjust it using `$.ajaxSetup` like [this](https://gist.github.com/ilyakhokhryakov/5229049).

Comment: I'll fool around with this. I suspect it's some auth issue. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with this stuff at all...to my own detriment.

Comment: Update. I'm thrilled. I got a 'success' message in the console by adding `xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content"));` to the `setHeaders` function on `fineuploader.js`. Though, the image is not changed for the user...now what?!

Comment: Got it using `.update_attributes({:image => file})`. Can you update your answer to include that the valums.js file needs to be updated around line 3277?

Answer (score 1):

If you have posted your entire routes, then you are missing the endpoint route. Eg:

```
put "/avatar" => "your_controller#update"
```

ps: adapt the http verb on client or server side (put or post)

And your `update` JSON outputs should look like (according to valums project wiki):

```
if @photo.save
  render json: {:success => true, :src => @photo.image.url(:thumb)}
else
  render json: @photo.errors.to_json
end
```

Comment: Can you give me a more proper controller method? I'm using carrierwave and mongodb...

Answer (score -1):

That error means that you are not returning valid JSON in your response.  Please see the poject's [server-side readme](http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/server/) for more information.  Another possibility is that your endpoint address is incorrect.

Comment: How can I debug the endpoint address? Wouldn't the endpoint be the same as the controller function? 'home/avatar'?

Comment: I'm not a rails guy, so I can't help you there.  Only you can determine what the address of your endpoint is.  I'd start by looking at the HTTP request/response.

Comment: Ray, I appreciate your feedback, but if you can't offer a Rails specific answer, I can't accept. I can easily find out what you've offered by a quick google search.

Comment: I understand Kevin, but the solution to your problem is really very simple.  You either are not specifying the correct endpoint address, or you are, but your server-side code is not returning valid JSON.  How can you determine if your code is returning valid JSON?  Look at the raw response and make use of [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/).  If your endpoint is wrong, no one can possibly help you with that.  You'll need to figure out the correct address to your server.  Also, your response content-type should be text/plain, not application/json.  This is detailed in the readme.

Comment: Thanks, Ray. Maybe the issue could be in my routes file (I know you're not a rails guy)...If you have the time, I'm new to Rails/programming, can you tell me why the response should be text and not json?

Comment: I explained this in the [FAQ](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/blob/master/docs/faq.md).  Please have a look at the 2nd question from the top.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this issue. You may want to consider this question in your next release. (Also, if I've paid for the .js, how do I get subsequent releases?)